# Trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 Express database with SQL Server authentication always result in "Login failed for user '...'."

Tags: java, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-express, jtds

I am using jTDS to connect a Liferay instance to an SQL Server 2008 Express server using the SQL Server authentication (instead of the Windows' auth method). I have something like this in my `portal-ext.properties`:

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/somedb
jdbc.default.username=someuser
jdbc.default.password=somepassword
```

(For those that do not know Liferay, it is somewhat alike to call

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/somedb",
                                  "someuser", "somepassword");
```

However, although I pass the correct username and password, it keeps going wrong with the message `Login failed for user 'someuser'`. I am dead sure the server login, the database user and the database exists and are well configured.

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I suppose there can be infinite reasons for such an error. In my case, nonetheless, the solution was the following:

1. Enable the TCP/IP connection in SQL Configuration Manager.
2. Open the SQL Server Management Studio (if you do not have it installed, install it; it can have [its own pitfalls](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/02/18/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010.aspx), however).
3. Right-click on the database server (as in the picture below) and click in `Properties`.
   [image: Right-clicking on the database server]
4. Select the `Security` option and mark `SQL Server and Windows authentication mode`. Click in OK.
   [image: Database server Security properties]
5. Open the SQL Server Configuration Manager and restart the SQL Server service.

After this, I got my connections without problems. [This article](http://www.ehow.com/how_7731123_connect-jtds-driver-sql-express.html) helped me a lot.